# Postfix: Temporary internal error / Dovecot: Initialization failed

Tags: debian, postfix, smtp, dovecot, imap

Today I wanted to make a mail server, but it did not work. Can you help me ?
I followed this tutorial: https://www.linode.com/docs/email/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql

Errors obtained:

```
Sep 19 19:40:15 ungarscool1-1 dovecot: lmtp (2273, contact@doamin.tld): Error: user contact@domain.tdl: Initialization failed: namespace configuration error: inbox = yes
Sep 19 19:40:15 ungarscool1-1 dovecot: lmtp (2273): Disconnect from local: Successful quit
[Private / dovecot-lmtp], delay = 0.08, delays = alpha.domain.tdl [private / dovecot-lmtp], delay = 0.08, (Private / dovecot-lmtp) said: 451 4.3.0 <contact@domain.tdl> Temporary internal error (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

Of course I changed my domain name to domain.tdl.

My dovecot configuration:

```
! include_try /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/*.protocol
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp


dict {
  #quota = mysql: /etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext
  #expire = sqlite: /etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext
}


! include conf.d / *. conf

! include_try local.conf

postmaster_address=postmaster@domain.tdl
```

Postfix configuration:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (UngarscoolOS)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no


readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

#Enabling SMTP for authenticated users, and handing off authentication to Dovecot
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_unauth_destination

myhostname = alpha.domain.tdl
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
#mydestination = domain.tdl, alpha.domain.tdl, localhost.domain.tdl, localhost
mydestination = localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

#Virtual domains, users, and aliases
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf,
        mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf
```

After `doveconf -n`

```
root@ungarscool1-1:~# doveconf -n
# 2.2.13: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 2.6.32-042stab123.1 x86_64 Debian 8.9 simfs
auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
postmaster_address = postmaster@domain.tdl
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 0
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: If this is really the Dovecot configuration you set up, you have some problems with spaces in locations where they should not be (for example file paths). What's the output of `dovecont -n`?

Comment: @JensErat I have modified my post with `doveconf -n`